# How to change file extension from .txt to .rtf in ios programmatically?

Tags: iphone

How do I change a file extension from .txt to .rtf in iOS programmatically?
In xml parsing I'm getting rtf data with rtf tags.
Is it possible to save data in a rtf file without tags? 
If we load that file, this was loading with rtf tags in webview.
If we open and save that file physically, it opens in the WebView.
Is there any way to do this task (File Open & Save) programmatically using iOS.

If we load the rtf file from FTP server, upto tables it was loading(only plain text before tables)

Answer (score 0):

using function of NSString

```
NSString *string2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"whateverFile.rtf"];
```

get the text only from the file and save it in .txt format using the

```
NSMutableString *mutstr2 = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
[mutstr2 setString: string2];
[mutstr2 writeToFile:@"whatevertxt.txt" atomically:YES encoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding error:&error];
```

you could write the file in .txt. format... i guess that is the best way to do what u want